# What is the story behind the design of the U.S.S. Enterprise in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

> I realize there have been many versions over the years.  What's the story behind the design of the first Starship Enterprise?

(from [Christine Choi](http://www.quora.com/Christine-Choi-1) via [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Trek-movie-TV-and-creative-franchise/What-is-the-story-behind-the-design-of-the-U-S-S-Enterprise-in-Star-Trek?share=1))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original Enterprise design and models were created by the art director [Matt Jeffries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Jefferies).  There is some small debate about the various [sources of inspiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701%29) that he drew from, but in general he drew on his background in aviation to come up with a design that had the feel of an aircraft, but yet didn't violate any of [Gene Roddenberry's rules](http://www.neatorama.com/2009/06/15/8-starship-enterprise-facts-every-trekker-should-know/) (i.e. shouldn't look like a rocket, no fins, no wings, no smoke trails, crew of 150, fantastic speed, etc).

He wanted a design that felt futuristic, yet practical.  After a bunch of attempts, they finally settled on the design that eventually became the Enterprise.  It featured a saucer section that served as the crew quarters and a main hull that served as the primary work areas, with two enormous power plants extending from the main hull.